# get taped item context or index in nativescript listview

Tags: javascript, listview, nativescript

i have list of movies and i want when user does tap on the movie to change page and go to details page with this movie details.

here is my listview:

```
<ListView items="{{ items }}" itemTap="{{ itemTap }}">
   <ListView.itemTemplate >
        <stackLayout orientation="vertical" class="itemBox">
            <Label class="title" text="{{ title }}" /> 
            <Image src="{{ poster }}" class="poster" />
        </stackLayout>           
    </ListView.itemTemplate> 
</ListView>
```

here is my itemTap function:

```
viewModel.itemTap = (args) => {
    const navOptions={
        moduleName:'details',
        context:{
            bindData:args.object.bindingContext
        }
    }
    console.log(args.object.items)
    topmost().navigate(navOptions);
}
```

this part args.object.items gives me full list but i dont know how to get current item which i taped.. please help

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, I just needed args.view.bindingContext instead of args.object.items